# How many times per day/month i can call url.fetch? (Какие есть ограничения по количеству url.fetch в день/месяц для google apps scripts?)

Tags: google-apps-script

Какие есть ограничения по количеству выполняемых запросов в день/месяц?

How many times per day/month i can call url.fetch?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which Google service you're using. As of right now, it varies between 20,000 to 100,000 calls per day.

[Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) are clearly specified.

- Consumer
  (e.g., gmail.com) = 20,000 / day
- G Suite free edition (legacy) = 50,000 / day
- G Suite Basic / Gov & G Suite Business / Enterprise / Education =  100,000 / day